# update dataframe with row_number column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a 243MB dataset. I need to update my Dataframe with row_number 
and I tried using the below methods:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("Rownumber",functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Now the row_number getting wrong after `248352` rows, after that `row_number` comes `8589934592` like this.

and also I used,

```
df.registerTempTable("table")

val query = s"select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Year) as Rownumber  from table"

val z = hiveContext.sql(query)
```

Using this method, I got the answer but this take more time. Hence I can't use this method.

Same is the problem with `df.rdd.zipwithIndex`

What is the best way to solve this in spark-scala ? i'm using spark 2.3.0.

Comment: Is it really 243 megabytes? You shouldn't need Spark at all. And `ROW_NUMBER()`, as inefficient as is, shouldn't be a performance issue with such small amount of data. Neither should be `rdd.zipWithindex`. Still, you've enumerated all available methods (and `monotonically_increasing_id` works as it suppose to).